# Orthogonal matrices and linear isometries

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been stuck trying to prove this theorem for a while, so I decided to ask for someone's help here. The theorem goes as follows: "let $f$ be a linear isometry of some Euclidean vector space; then the matrix $M$ representing the transformation with respect to some basis $B$ is orthogonal iff the basis $B$ is orthonormal".

Thanks in advance for your contribution.

PS: the $\Longleftarrow$ direction is fairly trivial, the other one is giving me trouble.